# Verify AWS Access Keys Before Submitting to a Database

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I have a form where the user will enter the AWS Account Name, AWS Access Key, and AWS Secret Key and click submit to add the information to a table in a database. How would I validate the keys prior to them being added to the database?

[image: Form Demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reliable way to confirm not only the format, but also the validity of the keys, is to perform an operation using them.

Do something simple with the EC2 API that requires all three factors prior to storing them in the DB.

On a side note, *please* be sure you properly secure this database.  If it is compromised, so will be as many AWS accounts as you store the credentials to.

Comment: That seems to be the simplest way, and thank you for the advice.